# Can I apply for a Schengen visa while in a Schengen state?

Tags: schengen

I am a Filipina on a short-term training program in Greece (3 months only) and was only given a single entry Type C Schengen Tourist Visa. I am nearing the end of my maximum 90-day stay but have been invited to extend for another 3 months. Can I apply for a visa here, or would I need to go back to my country and go through the whole application process again? Alternatively, would I be able to extend past the maximum 90-day stay usually held for tourists? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As I remember from my stay in the EU, you can.

Comment: You may be able to apply for a residence permit while you are in Greece.  You would otherwise need to return to your country to apply for a type-D ("national") visa; if you got a second type-C visa,  you would still have to stay away for 90 days before you could re-enter.

Comment: @spark the rules vary considerably from one country to the next, since longer stays are governed by national law.

Comment: When I was in Austria, it said you could apply for a new visa while there. Not sure about Greece though

Comment: In Germany, it depends on your citizenship wether or not you can apply for a long-stay visa while already in Germany. I am not sure if it is relevant in Greece, but it might help to answer your question if you mention where you are from.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo I am from the Philippines :)

Comment: @phoog Really? I did not know that I would have to stay away for 90 days before re-entry..

Comment: @CelestialAya only for a type-C visa.  For type C visas, the 90/180 rule cannot be waived.  But that rule does not apply to type-D visas or residence permits, so if you got one of those you would not have to stay away.

Answer (score -1):

In general, Visa's are granted in *your* country to go to another country. In a country that isn't your own, you try to get *residency*. Different process and paperwork. Also, can take forever. However, if you have what is necessary to apply for residency, then proof of application may be enough to no be considered in violation of your Visa, when it expires.

See if a local can help you, or find an office that works with work/travel migration.

Comment: Visas and residency are completely different things. Visas allow limited duration visits for specific purposes; residency is permission to live in a country for any purpose with no specific endpoint. The asker is very much asking about a visa: they want to remain in Greece for a specific, short amount of time, for a specific purpose.

Comment: @DavidRicherby in the Schengen area, a document that allows someone to remain in a country for a limited time and is issued inside the country by that country's authorities is generally known as a residence permit. So the asker is in fact asking about a residence permit.

Comment: Even without nitpicking on the technical and linguistic differences between a visa and a residence permit, this does not answer the question: Can OP apply for whatever document is required to stay *in Greece*, or does she have to return to the Philippines to do so.

Comment: Improve your reading. Clearly, she needs to check if proof of application suffices. Otherwise, leave. The terminology is important. I pointed out that to get a VISA you leave and get one from your in your own country, not in a foreign one.